# Only one Honeywell Home thermostat visible in Google home integration

Tags: home-automation, wifi

We recently installed a split system with 4 indoor units, and added 4 honeywell wifi thermostats for remote temperature control.  I then wanted to connect the thermostats to Google Home app.  but I found out that no matter what I don, only one of the 4 thermostats is visible to Google Home app.  Is there something I can do to make all 4 thermostats visible in the Google Home app?

Comment: Do you need to set the names on the 'stats so they are different?

Comment: The thermostats all have different names.

Answer (score 1):

Two things happened since I posted the question.

1. A few months after the post, the thermostats suddenly all started appearing in the integration.
2. Sadly it turns out that the Honeywell thermostats don't really work: they don't measure the temperature reliably, nor do they control the AC reliably.  Digging a bit deeper found dozens of people complaining of the thermostats not working.

I ended up throwing the Honeywell smart thermostats away and buying Cielo devices instead.  They work much more reliably and predictably. With that, the issue went away.

Comment: Are you sure they were real Honeywell thermostats and not cheap knock offs from China?   I'm intimately familiar with Honeywell thermostats and how they develop and test them...Honeywell doesn't produce garbage.

Comment: Their serial numbers check out and the devices take firmware updates from Honeywell. I think this is about as sure as one can get.